# quick sorting a char array in C

Tags: c, quicksort

I copy an `int` array in order to try [the quick sort algorithm from here](http://www.comp.dit.ie/rlawlor/Alg_DS/sorting/quickSort.c).

Then I change the type of the array to `char`. Here is the edited code:

```
extern void quickSortChar(char a[], int left, int right)
{
    int j;
    if (left < right)
    {
        j = partition(a, left, right);
        quickSort(a, left, j - 1);
        quickSort(a, j + 1, right);
    }
}

static int partition(char a[], int left, int right)
{
    int pivot, i, j, t;
    pivot = a[left];
    i = left; j = right + 1;

    while (1)
    {
        do i++; while (a[i] <= pivot && i <= right);
        do j--; while (a[j] > pivot);
        if (i >= j) break;
        t = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = t;
    }
    t = a[left]; a[left] = a[j]; a[j] = t;
    return j;
}

void main()
{
    char arr[] = "bacgd";
    puts(arr);
    quickSortChar(arr, 0, strlen(arr) - 1);
    puts(arr);
    system("pause");
}
```

I expect the output to be: `abcdg`, but output is: `abcgd`

Comment: `void main` is wrong. `main` should return `int`.

Comment: Why did you copy random code you don't understand in your program instead of just using `qsort`?

Comment: In the quickSortChar(), replace quickSort(a, left, j - 1) with quickSortChar(a, left, j - 1) and quickSort(a, j + 1, right) with quickSortChar(a, j + 1, right).

Comment: This program cannoit produce _any_  output because it doesn't even compile.

Comment: @melpomene I understand questioning why copying a code which you don't understand but do you also ask people, why would you try to bake a cake for yourself instead of just buying one from the store. I think the obvious reason why people still do sorting/linked lists etc. is because they want to try it themselves

Comment: @Philipp That's different. Implementing an algorithm yourself can be a good exercise. This question is more like "I bought this cake from a store; why does it taste bad?". In other words, OP isn't trying to debug his own code (actually he's not trying to debug anything, he's just asking what the problem is).

Comment: @melpomene That's why I said I understand questioning why copying a code which you don't understand because I agree with you on this. I guess your point was, if you copy code why not just use qsort. I still give OP the benefit of the doubt that he actually wants to learn something and that's the reason why he doesn't use just qsort in the first place.

Comment: @Philipp Then my question would be: If you want to understand quicksort, why are you just copying someone else's code?

Comment: @fvu: That's an interesting interpretation of SO philosophy.  I don't think it is accurate.

Comment: Too focused on the algorithmn, didn't realize I made such a mistake....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `quickSort()` recursively (wrong function name) inside `quickSortChar()`.

After fixing this bug, it runs and produces good output on my machine:

```
$ ./program
bacgd
abcdg
```